# Legendre Polynomials Recursion Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Using the recurrence equation for Legendre Polynomials:
$$(k+1)P_{k+1}(x)=(2k+1)xP_k(x)-k P_{k-1}(x)  \text{  , } k \in \mathbb{N}$$
Compute the Integral:
$$ \int_{-1}^1xP_k(x)P_{k+1}(x)dx $$
I am completely at lost as how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: The integral follows quickly from the above recurrence and the orthogonality relation for Legendre polynomials. That will certainly be included in whatever source text you're using for this problem.

Comment: Indeed, the missing piece is the orthogonality relation $\int_{-1}^1 P_nP_m \, dx = \frac{2}{2n+1}\delta_{mn}$.

Answer (score 0):

Although the hints above should be enough to solve this yourself, I will give the solution here:

$\newcommand{\partial}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$
$\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
\begin{equation}
xP_k(x)=\frac{k+1}{2k+1}P_{k+1}(x) + \frac{k}{2k+1}P_{k-1}(x)
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I&=\int_{-1}^1 xP_k(x)P_{k+1}(x)dx
\\ &=\frac{1}{2k+1}\int_{-1}^1 [(k+1)P_{k+1}(x) + kP_{k-1}(x)] P_{k+1}(x)dx
\\ &=\frac{1}{2k+1}\bracket{(k+1)\int_{-1}^1 P_{k+1}^2(x)dx + k\int_{-1}^1 P_{k-1}(x)P_{k+1}(x)dx}
\\ &=\frac{1}{2k+1}\bracket{(k+1)\cdot \frac{2}{2(k+1)+1} + k\cdot 0}
\\ &=\frac{2k+2}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Of course, this derivation requires $k>=1$ because otherwise $P_{k-1}(x)$ has no meaning.
For $k=0$ though, the integral evaluates to
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I&=\int_{-1}^1 xP_0(x)P_1(x)dx
\\ &=\int_{-1}^1 x^2dx
\\ &=\partial{\frac{x^3}{3}}_{-1}^{+1}
\\ &=\frac{2}{3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

so the formula above also holds for $k=0$.